# Creating an information table for a game

Tags: c#, windows, overlay

I am interested in integrating an external project with the game Lineage 2. I do not have developer access.

I envision that my project would have a Form, that show the status of the top 100 Player V Player. I have had some luck with receiving the top 100 list and such that is not my problem

My problem is, how is it possible to get my form, to be overlaid on the game's screen. I would also like for it to be shown but not to receive input.

Comment: I'm not sure I like the Idea of the OS allowing applications to run in the foreground like that.

Comment: @Zavis: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I would suggest editing your question to help attract more people who might be able to answer it. First, your question is about overlaying an app on top of a full-screen app. I would suggest making the title something to that effect. Second, only put the important text into your question. You can basically remove the first two paragraphs. Third, let us know what you used to create the form (Windows Forms, WPF Forms, some other form library)?

Comment: Is it a full screen application or also a form?

Comment: I don't believe L2 monitors process memory, so just inject some draw code into Core.dll.

Comment: No worries, I think I got what you were trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

My experience with overlaying a windows form on top a full-screen application such as a game is going to be a very difficult task to do, but not impossible.  You can find an example that was done in the XNA game development forms here: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/367591-mdxc-overlay-sample/